# Command Line Error - Last Parameter Overlooked?

Tags: bash, command-line, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I'm working to install Google Assistant SDK on my Raspberry Pi and I've run into an error. The [official Google Assistant SDK guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/register-device) was just updated (yesterday) so I can't find any other reports of this error, but the command to register a device using the registration tool is giving me some issues. The example command listed is listed as

`googlesamples-assistant-devicetool register-model --manufacturer "Assistant SDK developer" \ --product-name "Assistant SDK light" --type LIGHT --model my-model`

but I modified this command to be

`googlesamples-assistant-devicetool register-model --manufacturer "Assistant SDK developer" \ --product-name "Assistant SDK light" \ --type LIGHT \ --model my-model`

(adding in additional '\' after parameters)
and nearly got it to work this way, but get the error,

```
missing option "--model"
```

But when I switch the position of the `--type` parameter and the `--model` parameter I get the error

```
missing option "--type"
```

so I know the last argument in my command is just being overlooked, I'm just not sure why. The example command is obviously a little rough since I already had to edit it a bit, but I'm not familiar enough with the command line to edit it any further. I'm hoping someone with a little more experience can look over my syntax and let me know why part of my command is being ignored. Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you've shown, your problem is the use of so many back slashes.

The original commands probably broke the arguments up across multiple lines, for readability.  A back slash before a newline stops the newline from ending the command.

Looks like you took out the new lines, but not their attendant backslashes. This meant the backslashes applied to the following *space*  instead.  A space (or spaces) separates arguments from one another.  A back slash also escapes spaces; in this case, the spaces are preserved as *part of the argument*.  So `--model` becomes `' --model'`.  Probably several of your arguments are broken; likely it's the order they're checked by the program that determines which are in the error.

You shouldn't need any backspaces in that command from what I can see.  Take them out, and your results should improve.

Comment: Thanks so much! I obviously didn't know that about backslashes, and after removing all of them I got it to work! Thanks for the help!